# Java Play! 2 - Cache.remove

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ehcache

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaCache

Atm i can't find the Cache.remove method. I guess it's not implemented yet?

Then I would need to use a 3rd party library cache solution such as memcached for now.

```
// 2.0 final
Cache.set("item.key", null, 0)
// later
Cache.remove("item.key")
```

Comment: What version of Play 2 are you using?

Comment: At the moment I am using 2.0.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although it's totally unclear it can be read as:

Since `Play 2.0 final` to remove cache entry use:

```
Cache.set("item.key", null, 0);
```

(it will set cache for `item.key` with `null` value, which will expire after 0 seconds)

'later' means that somebody forgot to add this method and it will be added later ;)

**Edit:**

This issue is already addressed in [Play's Lighthouse](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/254-add-a-cacheapiremove-method)

Comment: thanks, this will do it for now :). Btw is there a changelog for each version of play! available? I am trying to find some information about 2.0.3.

Comment: yea, there is Lighthouse, actually I'm trying to check if the problem is addressed there, but... https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/milestones/150181-203

Comment: @MaikKlein there is also possible to preview it stone-by-stone: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/milestones/completed